# Is it possible emit data to channel in laravel echo?

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, socket.io, laravel-echo

I have two separate laravel project and installed on one of these project `laravel-echo` and on another one `laravel-echo-server`.

I connected this project together and transfer data from server to client but I can't emit data from client to server.

event in server:

```php
class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $prices;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param int[] $prices
     */
    public function __construct($prices = ['a' => 11000, 'b' => 420])
    {
        $this->prices = $prices;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('bla-bla');
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'financial.prices';
    }
}
```

rotue in server:

```php
Route::get('/fire', function () {

    $prices = [
        'a' => rand(11000, 120000),
        'b' => rand(450, 5000)
    ];
    event(new \App\Events\TestEvent($prices));
    return 'done';
});
```

client:

```js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.io = require('socket.io-client');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
    logToConsole: true
});

window.Echo.logToConsole = true;

window.Echo.join('bla-bla')
    .here((data) => {
        console.log('asdasd');
    })
    .joining((data) => {
        console.log('asdasd');
    })
    .leaving((data) => {
        console.log('asdasd');
    });
```

how can I do this? It would be highly appreciated if anyone can advise me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use emit after connected to the socket server:

```js
window.io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io('https://localhost:8080');

socket.on('connect', () => {
    socket.emit('your_channel_to_emit', {your_data});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Echo will use the `/broadcasting/auth` endpoint to authorize channel access. If your client side is not on the same host you will have to customize the authEndpoint of pusher. You may specify your own authorization endpoint by passing the `authEndpoint` configuration option to your Echo instance:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your-pusher-channels-key',
    authEndpoint: '/custom/endpoint/auth', //customize here.
});
```

Comment: authentication is right but I get this warnings:
```
[4:44:25 PM] - SLqtMNvkcfkY8aZvAAAA authenticated for: presence-bla-bla
Unable to join channel. Member data for presence channel missing
[4:44:25 PM] - SLqtMNvkcfkY8aZvAAAA joined channel: presence-bla-bla
```

Comment: That's a completely different problem than your question. You're out of this discussion. You can find more information [here](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server/issues/278)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Event (App\EventName):

```
public function broadcastWith()
{
    return [
        'data' => "your data",
        'moredata' => "more data",
    ];
}
```

And access your data like this in JS:

```
Echo.channel('channel-name')
    .listen('EventName', (event) => {
        console.log(event.data);
        console.log(event.moredata);
        console.log(event['moredata']);
    }
```